# Sort wav files based on channel #

Tags: 20.04, files, directory, sort, wav

Is there a way to sort wav files based on channel number in a directory?

For example, if I click Channel # for sorting it would. I'm surprised Ubuntu does not have this function.

Comment: There are a billion different bits of metadata that a system could sort on. I've been working with computers since the mid-90s and you are the first person I've seen ask this question. I would be surprised if any OS (aside from Ubuntu Studio) supported this feature out of the box 

Comment: Windows offers that feature, but I refuse to use Windows. Is there any code I could write to just sort the files based on channel number?